# Bash rename a file using yesterdays date

Tags: bash

I have a file with todays date in the this format:

```
testfile - 2014-10-07-08-01-30.CSV
```

i need to rename the file to:

```
newone_2014-10-06.CSV
```

Notice that the date is changed to the previous day.

I will run this out of a cron every day.
How would I do this in a bash script?

Comment: Previous date as of now, or previous date as of the filename?

Comment: Why are you rolling the "datestamp" back on a dated file like this? What's the situation here?

Comment: One file per day will come in with the current date.  As to why?  Do we ever really get the answer to those type of questions from our customers????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mv "testfile - $(date +'%Y-%m-%d')-08-01-30.CSV" "newone_$(date -d '-1 day' +'%Y-%m-%d').CSV"
```

Comment: This will only work if the file has been created exactly at `08:01:30`. Not very stable...

Comment: @hek2mgl has a good point. If you _know_ there will only be *one* file with that date/time stamp it might actually be better to glob than spell out the time stamp as the glob would only expand to one file anyway. I would not call it safe, but it would probably be more predictable/stable in behavior. Ex: `mv "testfile - $(date +'%Y-%m-%d')-*.CSV` or `-08-*.CSV`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `date` command:

```
filename=$(date -d "-1 day" +'%Y-%m-%d')
```

The date command supports to specify relative timestamps like `-d '-1 day'`.

To rename the file use the `mv` command:

```
mv -v old_file_name "testfile - $(date -d "-1 day" +'%Y-%m-%d').CSV"
```